# Javascript split not working

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string, I just want the first half, before the &.
So naturally, you would think this would work...

```
 var string = "EAAzqcZChQwMt3eJjGTucj1Illzr2v1oJsIY1NHulzZDZD&expires_in=4994";
 string.split("&");
 console.log(string[0]);
```

You would think string[0] would return

```
  EAAzqcZChQwMt3eJjGTucj1Illzr2v1oJsIY1NHulzZDZD
```

But it returns

```
  E
```

What gives?  Hopefully Im just being an idiot, and need to go to bed soon.  But I can't see whats wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

> [**`String#split`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns `array`, you are suppose to access value by passing `index`

In your example, you are accessing the `first-character` from variable *string* which is `E`

```js
var string = "EAAzqcZChQwMt3eJjGTucj1Illzr2v1oJsIY1NHulzZDZD&expires_in=4994";
var split = string.split("&");
console.log(split[0]);
```

Comment: Isnt that what Im doing with [0].  Thats the index I want access to.  The first half of the string?

Comment: You're too tired, go to bed. :)

Comment: @KyleK – `split` returns a new value, it does not manipulate existing `string` variable..

Comment: @KyleK note the different variables **string** and **split**

Comment: Thanks, I dont know whos answer to accept, since technically you're both correct. Maybe I should just delete this question altogether, cause it makes me look like a complete idiot. lol

Comment: @KyleK By `string[0]` you were indexing the first character of the original `string`, classic :-D